# Add a Method to Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, java-stream, streamex

While working with Java 8 [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)s, I some times find that [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) doesn't have a particular method that I desire (e.g. [takeWhile()](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/master/src/main/java/one/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx.java#L1523), [dropWhile()](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/master/src/main/java/one/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx.java#L1552), `skipLast()`).  How do I create my own stream class which has the additional methods with out re-writing the entire Java 8 [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) architecture?

I am aware of the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/) library and know that it has [takeWhile()](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/master/src/main/java/one/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx.java#L1523) and [dropWhile()](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/master/src/main/java/one/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx.java#L1552).  As of writing this, it doesn't have `skipLast()`.  I have filed [an issue](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/issues/58) for this method.

An acceptable solution would be to show how Java 8 [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) or [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/) can be extended.

Comment: Well you should probably create a wrapper class and write your own stream framework

Comment: You could create a stream with the indices and use `filter` to get the indices you want then map it back to the actual data. For instance printing everything except the last element in an array, `IntStream.range(0, array.length).filter(i -> i != array.length-1).mapToObj(i -> array[i]).forEach(System.out::println);`. But I do not think it is as nice as @LouisWasserman suggestion.

Comment: We're only talking about syntactic sugar here. Not a fan of static methods because they are an anti-pattern for stream syntax. However, if it's just for one method the cost of wrapping everything is not acceptable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 0.5.4 [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library has a [`chain()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#chain-java.util.function.Function-) method.  This allows for creating helper methods which plug in comfortably.

```
public static <T> UnaryOperator<StreamEx<T>> skipLast(int n)
{
   return(stream -> skipLast(stream, n));
}

private static StreamEx<T> skipLast(Stream<T> input, int n)
{
   // implement the real logic of skipLast
}
```

With the above, one can now write...

```
StreamEx.
   of(input).
   chain(skipLast(10)).
   forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Note that the same feature is suggested in OpenJDK bug tracker (see [JDK-8140283](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8140283)). You may vote for it in [OpenJDK mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/core-libs-dev) if you like it.